# Reading from Kafka hangs

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm reading from Kafka but the consumer hangs:

```
def produce(num, producer, topic_name):
    print("hello2")
    for i in range(num):
        future = producer.send('my-topic', bytearray("Hello Kayla 00", "utf-8"))
        try:
            record_metadata = future.get(timeout=10)
        except KafkaError:
            log.exception()
            pass

                     # Successful result returns assigned partition and offset
        print (record_metadata.topic)
        print (record_metadata.partition)
        print (record_metadata.offset)
```

This is the outputs:

```
my-topic
0
256
my-topic
2
298
my-topic
1
299
my-topic
0
257
my-topic
0
258
```

So writing works perfectly fine. Furthermore, I have visibility with another tool on Kafka and I can see myself writing.

The consumer is where the problem is:

```
def consume(num, consumer):
    print("WORK!!")
    for message in consumer:
        print("was here")
        print(message.value)
        if num == 0:
            consumer.close()
            break
```

The consumer never enters the `for` loop. It just print `WORK!!` and hands in the `for message in consumer` forever.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

This is how I setup the consumers and producers:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                         group_id="Bayern-Munchen",
                         bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                         auto_offset_reset='latest')



 producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers...)
```

Comment: have you tried with a new `group_id` and the `auto_offset_reset` set to "earliest"?